# what option is recommended for Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on dual-booting PC

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have only one computer with windows 8 installed and i would like to install Ubuntu 16.04 (without hurting my Windows 8 ). Installing Ubuntu there are three Options:
Option 1: Try before you install . Option 2: Install Ubuntu inside Windows and Option 3 : Something Else.
What is the best option any recommendation?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) and [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Try before you install.
Then install Ubuntu from within the live version using the option: Install Ubuntu alongside Windows